# Can you bring tax-free alcohol on Air Iceland Connect?

Tags: hand-luggage, iceland

I would like to bring some nice champagne with me and I know I can get as far as to [kef](/questions/tagged/kef) with it but am I allowed to bring it with me on board Air Iceland Connect as hand luggage from [rkv](/questions/tagged/rkv) to [aey](/questions/tagged/aey)?

I already have a full-sized hand luggage and I could probably squeeze the bottles in. It would be sealed in a vacuumed tax-free bag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just flew RKV-AEY with Air Iceland Connect and there were no issues bringing alcohol on the flight. It's best to have the bag checked though.

Answer (score 0):

If you purchased it at the airport and with the relevant closed bag etc I cannot see why they would not allow it, I very often carry all sorts of hotels of wine and perfumes as carry on that I bought at tax free during lay overs.

For example
SHA- HK - HCM I never have problems buying things in HK and bring

SHA - SGP - MEL, same thing

SHA - ARN - NYC same thing

I am trying to think of a place where I have been denied but I cant

Comment: Your experience is not universal, there are many stories of airports not allowing alcohol on transfers.